# What is the min buffer value such that an array of ints will be sorted in increasing order?

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, list, sorting

**Problem:** Given an array of integers, find the minimum buffer value such that the array can be sorted in strictly increasing order. Each element in the array can add or subtract up to the buffer value.

```
Ex: [4, 0, 9, -2]
```

The minimum buffer value is 6, because you can change the array into:

```
[4 - (6 or 5 or 4 or 3), 0 + (-1 or 0 or 1 or 2), 9 - (6) = 3, -2 + (6) = 4]
```

I believe I have a solution that works O(N^2), but I'm wondering if I can do better.

**EDIT: never mind, my solution doesn't work.**

**My solution:**

For each element, draw a line with slope 1 passing that element. Find the smallest buffer value that allows every element to be shifted onto the line. Keep track of the buffer values obtained and return the smallest one at the end.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain a litter better. Perhaps with your N^2 algo.

Comment: so basically you don't want to sort the array but transform it into a sorted sequence by adding/substracting a value in a range [0,n] and you call n the buffor? in that case 8 isn't the minimum, you can do it with 6 => [0 (4-4),1 (0+1),3 (9-6),4 (-2+6)].

Comment: also do you just need to find the value or also the sequence you can get with it? If my both comments are right then it might be doable in linear time using some observation and dynamic programming.

Comment: Please change the title of the question `max buffer` or `min buffer` ?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk oh shoot, you're right. My solution is wrong then. We don't need the sequence, we only need the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`O(n)` can be achieved by looping the array one by one and keeping the invariant correct and keeping track of the current buffer size:

1. we start from left and go one by one to the right
2. a single element subarray is by definition sorted
3. adjust the current element using our current buffer to the lowest possible value (so the invariant still holds)
4. if current element (after adjustment) is bigger than the previous element then we do not need to do anything (**sorted**)
5. otherwise (**unsorted**) we need to update the buffer (increase it) - this is done trivially by checking the difference in the current element and the max of the already sorted array which is simply the previous element ( so we add `abs((curr-prev)/2) + 1` to the current buffer) and the previous/current values (to the smallest values possible). At this point we don't need to care about earlier entries because since we are increasing the buffer to decrease the previous/current values we could simply subtract up to `abs((curr-prev)/2) + 1` from each previous value and the invariant would hold.

Some examples to make it all more clear (bolded - current, italic - previous):

> I) Input: [4, 0, 9, -2]

- [**4**] - sorted by definition
- [*4*,**0**] - unsorted, update current one with buffer [*4*,**0**], diff = (4-0)/2+1 = 3 => [1,2], buffer = 3 // the update is done as follow: decrease the previous value by the whole diff, for the current one check if newPrevious (1 here) plus 1 is in range current+-diff, if yes then set newPrevious+1, otherwise set current+diff
- [1,*2*,**9**] - sorted, update current one with buffer [1,*2*,**6**] // here update is done similarly to the previous update but instead off doing current+diff we do current-diff
- [1,2,**6**,*-2*] - unsorted, update current one with buffer [1,2,*6*,**1**], still unsorted so diff = (6-1)/2+1 = 3, buffer = 6, [1,2,**3**,*4*]

Done, buffer = 6

> II) Input: [40, 31, 140, 131]

- [**40**] - sorted by definition
- [*40*,**31**] - unsorted, update current one with buffer [40,31], diff = (40-31)/2+1=5 => [35,36], buffer = 5
- [35,*36*,**140**] - sorted, update current one [35,36,135]
- [35,36,*135*,**131**] - unsorted, update current one [35,36,135,136]

Done, buffer = 5

> III) Input: [1,1,1,1]

- [**1**] - sorted by definition
- [1,**1**] - unsorted, update current one [1,1], diff = (1-1)/2+1=1 => [0,1] (because 0+1 is ok), buffer = 1
- [0,*1*,**1**] - unsorted, update current one [0,1,2], sorted
- [0,1,*2*,**1**] - unsorted, update current one [0,1,2,2], diff = (2-2)/2+1=1 => [0,1,2,3], buffer = 2

Done, buffer = 2

> IV) Input: [7,11,1,2,3]

- [**7**] - sorted by definition
- [*7*,**11**] - sorted, adjust [7,11]
- [7,*11*,**1**] - unsorted, adjust [7,11,1], diff = (11-1)/2+1 = 6 => [7,5,6], buffer = 6

  - **here** we can see that we do not need to check anything before 11 as all the previous numbers are smaller than 11 so if we do 11 - X we could simply do PREVIOUS - X and the invariant would still hold
- [7,5,*6*,**2**] - unsorted, adjust [7,5,6,7] <- invariant still holds, I simply didn't adjust the first 7 in the previous step
- [7,5,6,*7*,**3**] - unsorted, adjust [7,5,6,7,8]

Done, buffer = 6

> V) Input: [0,1,3,-15]

Up until [0,1,3] nothing changed

- [0,1,*3*,*-15*] diff = 10, adjust prev and current [0,1,-7,-6] - again here we can see that we increase the buffer from 0 to 10 so all numbers to the left of 3 and 3 itself can be decreased by 10 and the invariant will hold but for the rest of the algorithm we don't need to do this

Done, buffer = 10

> VI) Input: [1,2,3,4]

- [1] - sorted by definiton
- [1,2] - sorted, adjust by buffer 0
- [1,2,3] - sorted, adjust by buffer 0
- [1,2,3,4] - sorted, adjust by buffer 0

Done, buffer = 0

Answer (score 2):

**The original answer**

My original answer consisted of the following three steps. That algorithm works provided that the `max` value in the normalized array comes before the `min` value in the normalized array. The sample arrays that I was considering were [4, 0, 9, -2] and [0, 1, 3, -15].  Note that in both of those sample arrays, the `max` precedes the `min`. However, this algorithm fails if the absolute `min` in the array appears before the absolute `max`.  Two examples where the algorithm fails are [-15, 1] and [40, 31, 140, 131].

Step 1: subtract the array index from the value at that index

```
array:              4    0   9   -2
index:             -0   -1  -2   -3
                   ----------------
normalized array:   4   -1   7   -5
```

Step 2: scan the normalized array to find the min and max values

```
max =  7
min = -5
```

Step 3: subtract the min from the max and divide by 2 (rounding up if necessary) and there's your answer

```
(7 - (-5)) / 2 = 6
```

**The rationale and flaw in the original answer**

The idea behind my original answer was that the midpoint between the `max` and the `min` provided a `target` value that *every* entry in the normalized array could be adjusted to hit. The `max` and `min` being the farthest from the `target` required the largest adjustments and hence provided the answer.  However, after seeing hk6279's comment, I realized that it's possible to have multiple `targets` for the normalized array. For example, consider the array [40, 31, 140, 131].  The first step is

```
array:         40  31   140  131
index:         -0  -1    -2   -3
               -----------------
normalized:    40  30   138  128
```

The `target` for the first two numbers is 35 (reachable with adjustments of +-5). The `target` for the second two numbers is 133 (also reachable with adjustments of +-5).  So the answer is 5, and the adjustments to the array are

```
array:         40  31   140  131
adjustment:    -5  +5    -5   +5
               -----------------
sorted:        35  36   135  136
```

(Side note: the array [-15,1] also has two targets. The target for -15 is -15 with an adjustment of 0. The target for 0 (the normalized value of 1) is 0 with an adjustment of 0. So the answer is 0).

**The more complicated (but still O(*n*)) answer**

Step 1: Normalize the array by subtracting the array index from the value at that index.  This step is unchanged from the original answer.

Step 2: Define a data structure to hold information about the array entries.

```
struct Section
{
   int max;           // the maximum value seen in this section of the array
   int min;           // the minimum value seen in this section of the array
   int startIndex;    // the starting index for this section of the array
   int endIndex;      // the ending index for this section of the array
}
```

Step 3: Scan the normalized array while creating an array of `Section` structs.  (The `sectionsArray` may be as long as the `normalized` array.)  The rules for creating the `sectionsArray` are

```
initialize the first section as { normalized[0], normalized[0], 0, 0 }

for each subsequent entry in the normalized array
{
   if ( normalized[i] > currentSection.max )        // found a larger value than the current max
   {
      newSection = { normalized[i], normalized[i], i, i }   // create a new section and add it to the sectionsArray
      currentSection = newSection                           // the new section is now our current section
   }
   else if ( normalized[i] < currentSection.min )           // found a new minimum for the current section
   {
      currentSection.min = normalized[i]                    // update the min and end of the current section
      currentSection.endIndex = i;
   }
   else                                                     // normalized[i] is within the current range of values
   {  
      currentSection.endIndex = i;              // update the end of the current section
   }
}
```

Note that in this step, the max values in the `sectionsArray` are in strictly ascending order. This is important for the next step.

Step 4: Working backwards from the end of the `sectionsArray`, combine sections where possible. The rule for combining two sections is

```
if ( sectionsArray[i].min <= sectionsArray[i-1].min )       // bigger max and smaller min allows preceding section to be absorbed into the current section  
{ 
   sectionsArray[i-1].max = sectionsArray[i].max            
   sectionsArray[i-1].min = sectionsArray[i].min            
   sectionsArray[i-1].endIndex = sectionsArray[i].endIndex

   discard sectionsArray[i]
}
```

Step 5: Scan the `sectionsArray` to find the largest difference between `max` and `min`.  The largest difference, divided by two and rounded up if necessary, is the answer to the question.  Also, the midpoint between `min` and `max` is the target value for that section of the array (target values can be truncated).

**An example**

Consider the array [8,5,8,6,14,12,18,13]. First normalize the array:

```
Input array:    8   5   8   6  14  12  18  13
index:         -0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7
               ------------------------------
Normalized:     8   4   6   3  10   7  12   6
```

Then create the sections array:

```
{  8,  3,   0, 3 }   // started with 8, 4 became the min, 6 was in range, 3 replaced 4 as the min.  10 ended the section since it was higher than 8
{ 10,  7,   4, 5 }   // started with 10, 7 became the min.  12 ended the section.
{ 12,  6,   6, 7 }
```

Working backwards:  The 10,7 section can be absorbed into the 12,6 section resulting in

```
{  8,  3,   0, 3 }
{ 12,  6,   4, 7 }
```

The maximum difference is 6, so the answer is 3.

The target for the first section is (8+3)/2 = 5 (after truncation)
The target for the second section is (12+6)/2 = 9

The adjustments are:

```
Normalized:     8   4   6   3   10   7  12   6
Adjustments:   -3   1  -1   2   -1   2  -3   3
               -------------------------------
Targets:        5   5   5   5    9   9   9   9
```

Apply those same adjustments to the input array:

```
Input array:    8   5   8   6   14  12  18  13
Adjustments:   -3   1  -1   2   -1   2  -3   3
               -------------------------------
Sorted:         5   6   7   8   13  14  15  16
```

**Applying this technique to other arrays seen in this thread**

```
input:         4   0  9  -2
normalized:    4  -1  7  -5
sections:      { 4, -1, 0, 1 }  { 7, -5, 2, 3 }
combined:      { 7, -5, 0, 3 }
answer:        (7 - (-5)) / 2 = 6
targets:       one target for the entire normalized array => (7 + (-5)) / 2 = 1

input:         0  1  3  -15
normalized:    0  0  1  -18
sections:      { 0, 0, 0, 1 }  { 1, -18, 2, 3 }
combined:      { 1, -18, 0, 3 }
answer:        (1 - (-18)) / 2 = 10
targets:       one target for the entire normalized array => (1 + (-18)) / 2 = -8

input:         -15 1
normalized:    -15 0
sections:      { -15, -15, 0, 0 }  { 0, 0, 1, 1 }
combined:      same as above
answer:        0 (same answer for both sections)
targets:       targets are -15 and 0

input:         40  31  140  131
normalized:    40  30  138  128
sections:      { 40, 30, 0, 1 }  { 138, 128, 2, 3 }
combined:      same as above
answer:        5 (same answer for both sections)
targets:       targets are 35 and 133
```

**The challenge**

Find a counter example that breaks this algorithm and post it in the comments :)

Comment: Fails for [-15 , 1]. Need to check if array is strictly increasing order beforehand.

Comment: @hk6279 thanks for pointing that out! Such a simple example, yet it forced me to completely redesign the algorithm.  Looking forward to seeing your counter-example to the updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using a binary search.

- So assume that the size of the buffer is x = (low + high)/2, what you could do is from each index from 0 to n - 1 (with n is the number elements), you just need to calculate what is the minimum value 
  it can take using buffer x (with condition that it should be greater than the last element). This greedy will help you to verify find if x can be a valid solution.
- Example , if x = 6, array is [4,0,9,-2]

  ```
  index 0, min is 4 - 6 = -2
  index 1, min is 0 - 1 = -1 (as we need to make this greater than -2)
  index 2, min is 9 - 6 = 3
  index 3, min is -2 + 6 = 4
  ```

  So, 6 is valid.

Pseudo - code:

```
 int low = 0;
 int high = //n times Max absolute value in the array
 while(low <- high){
   int x = (low + high)/2
   if(x make the array become sorted)
      update min result;  
      high = x - 1;
   else
      low = x + 1;
 }
```

Comment: how do you set ```//... something```? also when you have ```x``` how do you easily check if it can make the array sorted?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk for each element in the array, we can use x so that we make each element as small as we can, and fulfill the condition that it need to be greater than the previous element, starting from first element. So by this greedy, we can always know that whether x is a valid element. (Because if the previous element is smallest, so the next element can have a plenty of chance to be larger than the previous element, which make this greedy always can generate a solution if x is valid)

Comment: I will give you half a credit because 1) it's O(nlogn) and not linear and 2) ```//Max value in the array``` fails for ```[0,1,3,-15]``` :-)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk ha ha, ok, so I just need a upper bound, so maybe (n* Max absolute value of all element)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk hmm not sure about linear solution, can you elaborate more :)

Comment: I'm still working on it myself :-))) my idea was to find the biggest and smallest elements, take their difference, get the ceiling of (diff/2) and add the distance between them but I didn't write down any formal proof or check too many cases as I'm at work :-))

So in our case we would have max=9, min=-2, ceil(11/2) = 6, distance 0 (neighbors) so we have our 6. In case ```[0,1,3,-15]``` we have max=3, min=-15, ceil(18/2) + 0 = 9 hm and here's where my algorithm fails short by 1.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk hmm, another answer from user3386109 has similar idea with yours, maybe it the correct one :)

Comment: Yeah adding/removing the index was my second idea but he was faster :-)

Comment: @user3386109 why you remove your answer? sorry I just missed it.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Sorry, but do you know why user3386109 remove his answer? I thought it is correct?

Comment: yes it was correct, as someone else pointed out he only needed to make a check if the algorithm is needed at the start. Doesn't change the complexity. Not sure why he deleted it.

Comment: The comment correctly pointed out that my answer was flawed, but it was much worse than the comment indicated.  After adjusting the array, you must find the largest difference between some large number in the array that's **followed** by a smaller number in the array.  Smaller numbers followed by larger numbers may or may not affect the outcome, that's the part I'm not sure of anymore. What I now realize is that there may be multiple target values for the adjusted array.  For example [40, 31, 140, 131]. The answer is clearly 5 resulting in [35, 36, 135, 136] but there are multiple targets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `O(N)` solution.

For a neighboring pair, say `a` and `b`, we need to adjust them if `a > b` happens. To adjust them into ascending order, we need to find an `X` such that `a - X < b + X`, which is equivalent to find `X` that satisfies `a - b < 2X`. Therefore we only need to scan the array once to find those pairs with `a > b`, and calculate `ceil((a - b) / 2)`, and answer the max.

An implementation that works can be written as below:

```
temp = a[0];
ans = 0
for (i = 1; i < N; i ++)
    temp = max(temp + 1, a[i])
    ans = max(ans, temp - a[i]);
return ceil(ans / 2)
```

Comment: hmm, what about [7,11,1,2,3], your algo is 5 right, but it is wrong!

Comment: yes i realize it after I read comments under your solution @PhamTrung. My solution returns array that is not strictly increasing. I need to do more thinking...

Comment: actually a worse case will be an array with all identical numbers, say [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]. Both of our algo returns 0 but actually not.

Comment: Hmm, a quick fix is ceil((a - b + 1)/2)

Comment: It's seems to relate to the total number of numbers that are sharing the same value after the first round of adjustment.

Comment: The O(nlogn) algo is correct, as it always check for validity :) also notice my upper bound